# js fetch fails with net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR when accessing different ports

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ssl, fetch

If I load a page using **localhost:85** and try to `fetch()` a resource from **localhost:8083** it gives me a `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` error.

I do not have SSL enabled on either side. Clearly this is all in a development environment, how do I work around it?

Comment: This is **CORS** problem. Protocol, host, and port of request and server must match.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev Is there any way I can export **CORS** out of chrome, print it out, and burn it?

Comment: Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS how to set up CORS headers.

Comment: *"I do not have SSL enabled on either side."* - Then why do you access these ports with SSL (otherwise you would not get an SSL error) if you know that these ports have no SSL enabled?

Comment: @AlexKudryashev: Why should have this anything to do with CORS? It is an SSL problem (network) and not a permission problem (CORS).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I'm not accessing them with SSL There's no mention/configuration of SSL in either of the sites' headers, connection, protocol, nor nginx configuration.

Comment: @SanchkeDellowar: Since this is a SSL error your browser clearly attempts to access the site with SSL. If the site is not SSL enabled that exactly is the problem. i.e. accessing a site with SSL which is not SSL enabled. Unfortunately you don't show any code but if you really have `http://` and not `https://` in your fetch then maybe there is some redirect to HTTPS in your current config or web application or there is some cached permanent redirect (301) from previous experiments.

Answer (score 0):

So far, the only reasonable solution I've had was to edit both of the sites to operate out of the same port, but just have Nginx redirect the location. In other words:

localhost:85 => localhost:85

localhost:85/site2 => localhost:8083